# How to merge all associations of objects in a collection in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a "Parent" model and each Parent is associated with a number of children. I would like to select a number of Parent and have a set of all children based on some criteria. Let's say we have

```
Parent.where([some condition])
```

How can I get a collection which is the union of the children of each Parent in the collection in one line? I would like to do something like the following, but inline.

```
Parent.where([some condition]).each do |p|
  children += p.children
end
```

Comment: Rails version 3 or 4 ?

Comment: You should be able to scope `Child` like so `scope :by_parent,->(parent_conditions) { joins(:parent).where(parent: parent_conditions)}` then call `Child.by_parent([some condition])`. If you want an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of the just the children that meet the `Parent` criteria. This assumes `[some condition]` is a valid hash of where values on a `Parent`.

Comment: I guess it is rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a bit of work-around but it will make your implementation clean.
 Like @engineersmnky said, in your `Child` model define a scope:

```
scope :by_parent,->(parent_conditions) { joins(:parents).where(parents: parent_conditions)}
```

Then you can get children based on parent condition like this:

```
@children = Child.by_parent(country: 'Australia')
```

**Edit:**

If you do not want to provide any condition as scope argument, then try this:

```
scope :by_parent,-> { joins(:parents).where(parents: {country: 'Australia'})}
@children = Child.by_parent
```

Comment: What if I have parent_condition already in place and don't wanna pass it?

Comment: OK, thanks. I found that the parent in where clause should be parents, which is the name of parent table.

Comment: Updated my answer, and nice to know that you implemented the elegant solution. :)

Comment: Your answer true in this way: `scope :by_parent,-> { joins(:parent).where(parents: {country: 'Australia'})}
@children = Child.by_parent`